Plotting NWS Forecast Data (GRIB Data) in Alaska which crosses the dateline
I am trying to plot the National Weather Service Forecast data over Alaska. NWS Data is in a GRIB2 format. After trying all the projections, it seems ccrs.PlateCarree() is the only one where the data looks reasonable for the most part. However, I am having an issue with some of the timestamps as the data crosses the dateline. Any ideas on how I can resolve this? Notice the green line extends out of the bounds due to the crossing of the dateline in the data. Thanks! NWS Minimum RH Forecast for Alaska
I tried a bunch of different projections, specifically the North Polar Stereographic since that should have resolved the issue in my mind but unfortunately it still didn't work. Also I set the central_longitude=180 and it plotted the data waay outside of the bounds of the Alaska forecast grids (plotted it all throughout Canada and Russia etc. going off the page).
